simple example to pass a+b to a dll in C++and get the dll to ceturn c?
I am trying to create a wrapper dll. So far I made one .dll that sums a and b. Then I used the tutorial here
https://www.nerdthings.dev/2020/08/06/understanding-loadlibrary, but did not get anywhere. Suppose need something simpler.
Cannot even compile it
DLL1 has the function plus, which adds a and b to c. Then I want to make DLL2 that passes in1 and in2 into DLL1 and shoulc get out back
In the tutorial
FN_exampleFunction exampleFunction = (FN_exampleFunction) GetProcAddress(foo, "exampleFunction");
int retValue = exampleFunction();
everythibg is called exampleFunction....
First dll
header
#pragma once
#ifdef dll18_EXPORTS
    #define dll18_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define dll18_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" dll18_API void sumAB(
     double in1, double in2, double* out1);

main
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include "dll18.h"

void sumAB(double in1, double in2, double *out1)
{
     *out1 = in1 + in2;
}
void main()
{
     sumAB;
     return;
}

That compiles nicely, can get this dll to add 2 values. Now I want to make another .dll that asks this one
Header for DLL19 which is meant to read
#pragma once

#ifdef dll18_EXPORTS
    #define dll18_API \__declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define dll18_API \__declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" dll18_API void LVadd(double fromLV1, double fromLV2, double\* toLV);

Main for DLL19 which is meant to read DLL18
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "dll19.h"

typedef int(__stdcall *sumAB)(double in1, double in2, double* out1);

void LVadd(double fromLV1, double fromLV2, double* toLV)
{
    *toLV = fromLV1 + fromLV2;
}

void main()

{

    // First, load DLL18.dll

    HMODULE DLL18 = LoadLibraryA("DLL18.dll");

    LVadd = GetProcAddress(DLL18, "sumAB");
    FreeLibrary(DLL18);
}

Error is

'=': function as left operand Dll19   in the line
LVadd = GetProcAddress(DLL18, "sumAB");


This is for testing only. Need to make a wrapper dll, so need to work out how one dll talks to the other.

I’m confused. If the implementation of the add function is supposed to be in dll18, why does dll19 contain another complete definition of the same function? dll19 should only have a function pointer that is bound to dll18’s implementation.

You seem to have some misunderstandings about DLL's, functions and pointers to functions. If you define a function in the same translation unit as you use it, then you have the function defined in that TU. You don't load it from a DLL. And a function is not the same thing as a pointer to a function. A pointer to a function is a type, while a function is the actual function itself. Before continuing with DLL's, I recommend you spend some time to refresh your beginners material about functions and pointers to them.

Are you positive that you need to load you DLL dynamically at runtime with LoadLibraryA ? You can link a DLL statically (or rather "implicitly") too, which makes things way easier.  If you're on Windows, see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=msvc-170

I need to build a wrapper .dll. Something that pulls data from one dll and passes data to some other program. Can be static, can query once per second or so. For a start need to get it to work somehow

You've declared a function LVadd
extern "C" dll18_API void LVadd(double fromLV1, double fromLV2, double* toLV);

and then you have tried to assign to that function
LVadd = GetProcAddress(DLL18, "sumAB");

but that is illegal, you cannot assign to a function, a function is not a variable. I suppose you are getting confused between functions and function pointers. Function pointers are variables and can be assigned to.
To fix, remove the function declaration extern "C" dll18_API void LVadd(double fromLV1, double fromLV2, double* toLV); and also remove the function definition
void LVadd(double fromLV1, double fromLV2, double* toLV)
{
    *toLV = fromLV1 + fromLV2;
}

The function you are trying to call is in a different DLL, it makes no sense to repeat the function in this program. I guess you just added this because you were trying anything to get it to work.
Next add a function pointer declaration and assign to that
sumAB sumAB_ptr = (sumAB)GetProcAddress("sumAB");

Here the variable is called sumAB_ptr and the type of the variable is sumAB which is a function pointer type as you declared earlier
typedef int(__stdcall *sumAB)(double in1, double in2, double* out1);

Finally call the function in the other DLL using the function pointer
sumAB_ptr(2.0, 2.0, &result);
std::cout << result << '\n'; // should print 4

The final thing you should add is that with DLLs you should always check that you managed to load the DLL. It too easy for this to fail, so you should always check.
HMODULE DLL18 = LoadLibraryA("DLL18.dll");
if (!DLL18)
{
    std::cout << "DLL failed to load!!!\n";
    return;
}

EDIT
One other thing I noticed. Your function pointer is declared like this
typedef int(__stdcall *sumAB)(double in1, double in2, double* out1);

But your function (in the DLL) is defined like this
void sumAB(double in1, double in2, double *out1)

This is inconsistent, you have the function returning int in the first case and void in the second. They should be the same, either both int or both void.
EDIT
Another thing I have noticed is that your first DLL has a void main function. This is not needed, only programs have main functions. Just delete it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170  in visual studio one can set all this, so should try to get this to work

@StackoWhacko There are lots of ways to make this work. The page you linked to uses an import library which is a different technique that the one you were trying above. Either way the keys are; firstly understand the theory behind what you are doing, this stuff is too complex for just dumb copying to work (most of the time); and secondly attention to detail, one slip might be enough to stop everything working.

@StackoWhacko If I was doing this for myself, the import library technique is the one I would choose.

so here the code so far to pass values to the dll #include 
#include "DLL18.h"
int main()
{
for (int i{ 1 }; i <= 3; ++i)
{
std::cout << "please enter a 1st number: ";
double in1{};
std::cin >> in1;
std::cout << "please enter a 2nd number: ";
double in2{};
std::cin >> in2;
double out1{};
sumAB(in1, in2, &out1);
std::cout << "output out1: " << out1 << " , *(&out): " << *(&out1) << '\n';
}
return 0;

}

the dll      // dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include "dll18.h"
void sumAB(double in1, double in2, double* out1)
//need to declare output variable as well for Labview to find it
{
*out1 = in1 + in2;

}

as long as I get it to work somehow, still busy reading through learncpp.com. Now I got it working in a console app, I need to turn that into another dll. Then I get that wrapper.dll that talks to Labview
